# AngularJS or JQuery parse bad format JSON (http get)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, angularjs

I am trying to parse a bad json format from a remote server that is like this:

```
//[
{},{} 
]
```

My code in AngularJS:

```
$http.get('http://www.example.com/badjson')
    .success(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
});
```

but i get Error: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data.
I cannot get it working in Jquery with $.getJSON either. Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to get the raw response using the `transformResponse` function:

```
$http.get('http://www.example.com/badjson', { 
    transformResponse: function(d, h) { 
        return d; 
    }
})
.success(function(data) {
    conole.log(data);
});
```